# No Manager when Executing `Me.Request().Expand("Manager").GetAsync()`

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I get a null response for me.Manager when I run the following code:

```cs
var me = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().Expand("Manager").GetAsync();
```

But using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), the following does give me my manager:

> HTTP GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/manager

How do I get my manager using the MS Graph .Net Core SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I have to use the Beta version of Microsoft Graph since only that allows the expansion of managers in both the SDK and in the graph explorer. I used this instead and it worked:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/